# How to import function from module that uses ArgParser without passing args

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say I have two modules:

- a.py:

  ```
  import argparse


  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("arg", help="Some argument")
  args = parser.parse_args()


  def func():
      print('Hello world!')
  ```
- b.py:

  ```
  from a import func

  func()
  ```

When I execute `python3.8 '/home/b.py'`

I got

```
usage: b.py [-h] arg
b.py: error: the following arguments are required: arg
```

...even though `func` doesn't need to use system arguments to be executed

Is there any way I can import and execute `func` without passing system arguments to `b.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing script `a.py` to run at import time from script `b.py`. You just need to change it to:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("arg", help="Some argument")
    args = parser.parse_args()


def func():
    print('Hello world!')
```

Why this works is explained very well here so I won't rehash it! [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)